# Is the series convergent or not?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

$ S_{\infty}= \sum_{1}^{\infty}n^{-n-(-1)^n} $  does the summation converge ?

I tried using ratio test ! But can't come to a conclusion ! Any advice would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Looks like it was chosen specifically to escape the ratio test. Try anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n^{-n-(-1)^{n}}\leq \frac 1 {n^{n-1}} \leq \frac 1 {2^{n-1}}$ for all $n \geq 2$. Hence the series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, that:

$$\sum_1^{\infty}n^{-n-(-1)^n} < \sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}},$$

which clearly does converge.

P.S.: If $n$ in base and power still bothers you, use this:

$$\sum_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{n-1}} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \sum_3^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$